# arcpy.intersect_analysis: output shapefiles not saved?

Tags: arcpy, intersection

I am trying to write my first python code to use in ArcGIS 10.1.

I have feature classes in a file geodatabase .gdb, and AOI.shp (area of interest). I list my geodatabase feature classes, and want to intersect my list with AOI.shp.
I want to save my final intersected files.

Here is my code:

```
# import system modules
import arcpy, os
from arcpy import env

# Allow to overwrite existing files
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

# Set environment settings
env.workspace = r"C:\Users\...\extent_AOI\disturbaces_for_aoi.gdb"

# identify AOI
aoi = r"C:\Users\...\aoi.gdb\aoi"

# Set output database
out_wksp = r"C:\Users\...\disturbances_by_aoi.gdb"

# list features in the working folder database
fcl = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()

# print files to check them
print fcl

for fc in fcl:
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fc, aoi], out_wksp + fc, "ALL", "", "INPUT")
    print "intersection ok"
```

My code seems to run through PythonWin.

However, I can't find my output data in my output folder `out_wksp` ?

How can I save my output data correctly?

Comment: out_wksp + fc will not place the fc in your workspace, replace line of code - arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fc, aoi], out_wksp + "\\" + fc, "ALL", "", "INPUT")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your output filepath is not including slashes before the feature class name.  So if your feature class is called `tempFC` the output filepath is being generated as
`C:\Users\...\disturbances_by_aoi.gdbtempFC` rather than
`C:\Users\...\disturbances_by_aoi.gdb\tempFC`

Use `os.path.join()` to create a valid filepath:

```
for fc in fcl:
    outputFC = os.path.join(out_wksp, fc)
    arcpy.Intersect_analysis([fc, aoi], outputFC , "ALL", "", "INPUT")
```